# Sending emails from delphi code under citrix environment

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, mapi

our customers mostly uses MS Outlook, but sometimes also other clients gives us trouble creating a new mail window from code.

we tried also to implement a mailto: alternative, but using attachment="C:\filename.txt" fails.

right clicking on a file using send to mail recepient works mostly anyway, but I never found a way to do this by code.

is there any other ways to create a new mail with an file attachment?

we also experienced that the entire application crash because of the mapi code, the windows error pretty often gives an error looking like this :

```
Faulting module name: dhcpcsvc.DLL, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bd9b5
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00001d00
Faulting process id: 0x868
Faulting application start time: 0x01ca7fbc86a3e836
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
Report Id: c60fa358-ebaf-11de-8b4f-0026b9486d93
```

Comment: Could you attach the actual Delphi code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sMHAEEwP here is a quick paste, it fails at line 90 - 95 with wrong parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [**How can I simulate ‘Send To...’ with Delphi?**](http://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/how-can-i-simulate-send-to-with-delphi/)

The code shows how a new 'Compose mail' window can be opened with a file already attached, simulating the operating system default action for the 'Send to...' shell context menu.

Comment: I found a page which has somewhat I see translated to Delphi ---
http://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/how-can-i-simulate-send-to-with-delphi/ ---- I tried to modify this slightly to just accept a file using OpenDialog. http://pastebin.com/ZXpFrPET but I get an error message saying "Wrong Parameters" on the following line (unwrapped)         OleCheck(Folder.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, PWideChar(WideString(Files[i])), chEaten, p^[i], dwAttributes));

Answer (score 0):

> is there any other ways to create a new mail with an file attachment?

Yes. You can send directly using Indy: TIdSMTP + TIdMessage + TIdAttachmentFile.

Sample code:

```
IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
try
    IdMessage.Subject := 'YourMessageSubject';
    IdMessage.Recipients := 'targetmail1@example.com,targetmail2@example.com';
    IdMessage.CCList := ...
    IdMessage.BccList := ...
    IdMessage.Body.Text := 'YourMessageText';
    IdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.example.com';
    i := 1;
    TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, TFileName('YourAttachmentFileName'));
    try
      IdSMTP.Connect;
      IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
    finally
      IdSMTP.Disconnect;
    end;
finally
    IdMessage.Free;
    IdSMTP.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Disadvantage: it does not open a compose window which allows to edit the text or add recipients from the address book.

Comment: @mjn: It is true. If the real intention is to use the "MailTo" approach, your solution is better. If the intention is to send mail regardless the client machine has or not the "MailTo" command associate with a mail client, and also correctly configured, the direct send approach could be more appropriated.

Comment: My solution (which actually is only a mix of two other resources) does not depend on the mailto command association - see http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/sendtomail.html

Comment: @mjn do you have an Delphi translated version ?